# Azure - Debug web application without Azure Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a web application which is hosted by ourself.

We plan to host in Azure soon, so I add Azure project.

Now on, whenever I debug, Azure Emulator is loaded. It is very slow to debug in Emulator.

I uncheck Azure project for **Debug** in **Configuration Manager**, but it still debug with Azure Emulator.

***Is there anyway I can debug (like my old single web application) without Azure Emulator?*** I can delete Azure project while debugging, and create it again when ready to publish to Azure; however, it is not convenience.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We just converted our app from a Asp.net Web Application Project to full Azure Cloud Solution. Before it took just a few seconds to load our site in debug mode. Now it takes at least 5 minutes from hitting F5 to viewing a webpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set your web role project (not the azure/cloud one) as the startup project you should be able to debug the web (asp.net?) project normally (on development webserver, IIS or IIS express).

Comment: Is this still the best way?

Comment: As long as your app does not strictly depend on/can work without the Azure RoleEnvironment, yes. This will spare you several steps during application start-up compared to running it through the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

To debug your web application without starting the emulator you can simply right click the **web project**, choose **Debug** and then **Start new instance**:

[image]

Now, you'll have to watch out for one thing. By default, your web application will have the following in its web.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace>
    <listeners>
      <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Now, if you're using **Trace** and **Debug** in your application you'll need to comment this line out. If you don't do this, you'll end up having erros when logging using Trace or Debug:

*Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.*